# When to apply negative sign when number is squared

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recreational-mathematics

I always had this confusion of when I need to apply the negative sign in the calculation.
I understand that $(-1)^2 = 1$ however why isn't $-1^2 = 1$?

Comment: because $(-1)^2=(-1)*(-1)=1$, but $-1^2 =-(1^2)=-(1*1)=-(1)=-1$

Comment: Though beware Excel and some similar cases, where `=-1^2` gives `1` but `=0-1^2` gives `-1`, because if interprets the former as $(-1)^2$ and the latter as $0-(1^2)$, i.e. the first `-` as a unary operation taking precedence over exponentiation and the second `-` as a binary operation with exponentiation taking precedence over it

Comment: Just for an example, that's the same as writing $-1 \times 1^2 = 1$, which probably is pretty clear that it's not true

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When we write $-x^2$, it means we square $x$ first, then take the negative of this. That is, $$-x^2 = -\left(x^2\right).$$ So $$-1^2 = -\left(1^2\right)=-1.$$ (And thus $-x^2$ means something different to $(-x)^2$.)

Answer (score 1):

Unary minus has lower precedence than elevation to a power.

Answer (score 0):

As it is already in the previous answers:
$(-x)^2\neq-x^2$
To avoid confusion, it is better to use parentheses.  $-x^2=-(x^2)$